# How can i send a flask response in from forked child and not from original handler

Tags: python, flask, fork, gunicorn

I'm using the flask with the gunicorn.

I want that the stream of response will be constructed and returned from the different process, then I did fork for gunicorn and return it. Then child process commits suicide and parent finish the processing by returning its own response ("", 200). But, "curl localhost/preview -d'{}'" exits with error:
"Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data".

As I understand it, this is because parent writes it's own response to the stream of HTTP1.1 that already has been written by the child and break the "Chunked transfer encoding".

Can anybody give me an advice how can i handle this?

The simplified code I use:
https://gist.github.com/worroc/a5a97329cbda4b60941b44939c907868

Thanks a lot